# Android Google Maps V2 marker color

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I know I can set the hue of a `Marker` added to a `GoogleMap` with

```
gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(95)));
```

but this doesn't let me set the saturation and lightness. I need to have markers in a special color. 
1. Is there any possibility to do that programmatically, and if not
2. can I download the default marker icon somewhere to color it myself?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to do that programmatically

No.

> can I download the default marker icon somewhere to color it myself?

Maybe the drawable is inside GooglePlayServices.APK or maybe it is created programatically. If it is there it might not be legal to copy it to your project.

Anyway I would suggest posting a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) if you want it implemented.